# Linux: use OpenGL 4.x

Tags: c++, linux, opengl

How I can use OpenGL without *mesa*? It's terrible - supports max. OpenGL 3.1.
I readed about loading *openGL.so* with `dlopen` but where is file to load, and how I can hang that?

Ah, I forgot, language is `C++`

Comment: Mesa isn't terrible at all - shifting your complete misunderstanding of what OpenGL is to mesa is nonconstructive. What do you want, hardware accelerated GL 4.0? Then take one of modern video cards that supports it and use vendor-provided graphics driver - GL implementation is part of it (it works that way on all systems, nothing to do with linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just linking to libGL.so is all that is necessary to use the hardware graphics driver.

If you have an NVIDIA or AMD graphics card and you have installed the `nvidia` or `fglrx` driver, you will get the maximum OpenGL version supported by your video card.

If you instead are using the open source `nouveau`, `radeon`, `intel`, or other graphics driver, Mesa will take over and you will have only the maximum version of OpenGL supported by Mesa (3.1) and the driver for your hardware. It will automatically use all hardware features it's capable of using.

You do not need to do any fancy `dlopen` tricks or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL is an open API to "standardize" the access to graphics pipeline. The graphics pipeline is supposed to be in a GPU! But this is not necessary! [Mesa 3D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesa_%28computer_graphics%29) is a an open-source implementation of the OpenGL specification that also contains a software implementation of a graphics pipeline (yes, software-based) that is supposed to deliver the same result of a regular GPU graphics pipeline (except for the speed, of course!).

You don't have to use MESA if you have GPU! In order to try OpenGL, I suggest you to read some basic tutorial of OpenGL:

- http://duriansoftware.com/joe/An-intro-to-modern-OpenGL.-Table-of-Contents.html
- http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/

[dlopen()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen) is used to load dynamic libraries. If you use helpers like [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/) or [GLUT](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/) you don't need to care about those details.

Comment: Thanks for link - but how I can select video card for use? My friend has laptop with 2 video cards (integral and nvidia), and program without use `optirun` (from *bumblebee* package) supports only OpenGL 3.0/3.1.

Comment: Which OpenGL version is supported depends entirely on the driver (or mesa, which is kind of like a driver). So if your friend's GPU driver does only 3.0/3.1, that's it. Can't do a thing about it (except alternative drivers or updates).

Comment: Saying that mesa is software implementation isn't exactly correct. About every opensource GPU driver implemented as mesa backend. As for bumblebee - as i recall, it uses intel and nouveau drivers - both mesa backends. dlopen() isn't best suitable for this case - glXGetProcAddress should be used whenever possible. And, having 3.x (or any) version with appropriate extensions is almost no worse than 4.x+.

Comment: You are right @keltar... "Mesa is an open-source implementation of the OpenGL specification". I will give more precision to my answer!